# Maven Chronos JMeter plugin

Tags: testing, maven-2, jmeter, performance-testing

Has any one used [Chronos](http://mojo.codehaus.org/chronos-maven-plugin/index.html) for JMeter + Maven plug-in. I am having tough time trying Maven JMeter plug-in and thought of giving it a try

I have following pom set up for chronos but when I execute "mvn verify " I encounter following exception -

#

```
Maven cannot calculate your build plan, given the following information:

Tasks:
- verify

Current project:
Group-Id: chronos1
Artifact-Id: chronos1
Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
From file: C:\SelNG\chronos\pom.xml


Error message: Failed to resolve plugin for mojo binding: org.codehaus.mojo:chronos-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:jmeter
Root error message: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
```

#

Is it because plug-in is not available in repo?
My pom is -

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>chronos1</groupId>
  <artifactId>chronos1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>chronos1</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
        <jmeter.home>C:/Program Files/jakarta-jmeter-2.4</jmeter.home>
  </properties>

  <build>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>chronos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <configuration>
                          <input>${basedir}/src/jmeter/EducationSSL.jmx</input>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                          <execution>
                                <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                      <goal>jmeter</goal>
                                </goals>
                          </execution>
                    </executions>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
  <reporting>
        <plugins>
              <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>chronos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

Thanks
Tarun K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any particular experience with *this* plugin but for SNAPSHOT versions of codehaus plugins, you probably need to declare the codehaus snapshot repository:

```
<project>
  ...
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</id>
      <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    ...
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
</project>
```

Comment: You need

<url>https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/</url>

currently (although no doubt Pascal's answer was correct at the time)

Comment: Does this repo exist today?