# chronos-maven-plugin: cannot find mojo-sandbox-5-SNAPSHOT.pom when running maven

Tags: testing, maven, jmeter

This question is based on another question on stackoverflow: [Maven Chronos JMeter plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691048/maven-chronos-jmeter-plugin)

I have the same problem, but adding the pluginRepositories as suggested above doesn't solve the problem completely.

Here's an extract of my pom:

```
<project>
  ...
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>snapshots.repository.codehaus.org</id>
      <url>http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>chronos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <configuration>
      <input>${basedir}/src/test/jmeter/test.jmx</input>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>jmeter</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
...
</project>
```

I get the following maven error after maven has tried to get the mjjo-sandbox-5-SNAPSHOT.pom from different locations:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.codehaus.mojo:chronos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT

Reason: Cannot find parent: org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-sandbox for project: org.code
haus.mojo:chronos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT for project org.codehau
s.mojo:chronos-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: It looks very old...why not using the following: https://github.com/Ronnie76er/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki

Answer (score 4):

You seem to have used an old version of the plugin. All plugins at codehaus refers to a common parent. The old version of chronos was referring to and old version of the parent, which is no longer easily accessible.

Newer versions can be found by adding a repository location http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be something wrong with that plugin.

It used to work for us and I still have the working version in my local repo. First thing I notice, parent used to be mojo-sandbox-parent which is also missing from repo.

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>mojo-sandbox-parent</artifactId>
   <version>8</version>
</parent>
```

**Update**

I found answer here: [Where is org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-sandbox:pom:5-SNAPSHOT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901762/where-is-org-codehaus-mojomojo-sandboxpom5-snapshot)

You need to change repository to https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/
and, as a workaround, add http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/codehaus-snapshot-repo/

Here is JIRA ticket to fix this http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MSANDBOX-50