# Where is org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-sandbox:pom:5-SNAPSHOT?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm trying to use the javascript-maven-plugin from the codehause's mojo project.

When I execute any plugin goal, the following error is shown saying that mojo-sandbox-5-snapshot.pom has not been found.

I have tried with some repositories, including:
nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/
nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/
snapshots.repository.codehaus.org/
with no lucky.

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

GroupId: org.codehaus.mojo
ArtifactId: mojo-sandbox
Version: 5-SNAPSHOT

Reason: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.codehaus.mojo:mojo-sandbox:pom:5-SNAPSHOT

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  codehaus-snapshots (http://nexus.codehaus.org/snapshots/),
  codehaus.org (http://snapshots.repository.codehaus.org)
```

Where can I find this artifact?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

[Here it is](https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group/org/codehaus/mojo/mojo-sandbox/5-SNAPSHOT/)!

So, add: `https://nexus.codehaus.org/content/groups/snapshots-group` as a snapshot repository.

Comment: There is only md5 and sha1 files... no pom!

Comment: I find the pom in here:
http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/groups/public-snapshots/org/codehaus/mojo/mojo-sandbox/5-SNAPSHOT/